# Can't send values to class in different package because Package does not exist

Tags: java, netbeans, pass-by-reference

I am using NetBeans 8.0.2. I have searched several forums to get solution to my current situation. I can't access method of a different package inside of a class. I have imported the required package and tried to create an instance of the class. Firstly NetBeans puts a red line under the code saying that

```
"Package sts2 does not exist. <identifier> expected"
```

next when I try to access the method using the instanceName.methodName format it does not show a list of the available methods, it just shows new. 'sts2' is the name of the instance I created for 'Start2' class, 'Start2' class is inside of a package different from class that uses the retrieved input.  I have used the import statement to import the package required.

I have tried restarting NetBeans, restarting my computer but it's still same thing. Basically what I am trying to do is collect the values of variables and pass them around from one class to the other and carry out calculations using these values. These classes are GUIs that have to deal with user inputs.

Please note I have seen several posts about passing variables between classes but it is not really in line with my current predicament. Is it possible to do cross imports, like package A imports Package B to access its methods then in reverse Package B imports Package A to access its methods. What am I doing wrong here? Am I passing the values as I should be?

For further clarity see the code below (ignore that I have not used standard package names of the type com.name.barewithme). I am hoping to strengthen my knowledge and skills of JavaSE with this assignment.

The Start2 class that retrieves and sends the data.

```
package home;
import Solution_screens.*;

public class Start2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  //this is the Start2 class it recieves user input via GUI then sends to PayRoll class in different package ie Solutions_screens)
  public void calcDisp(){
    //this method is called from PayRoll class. it collects and sends the values over
    String firstname = jTextField1.getText();
    String sal1 = jTextField5.getText();
    float sal = Integer.parseInt(sal1);
    PayRoll p = new PayRoll(); //creating instance of the PayROll class so I can send retrieved values over there
    p.userInput(firstname); //userInput method is defined in PayRoll class
  }
  private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // this button was dragged in using NB DnD

    PayRoll payr = new PayRoll(); //another instance of PayRoll to make it visible
    payr.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Now the PayRoll class

```
package Solution_screens;
import home.Start2;

public class PayRoll extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  //here I only need the Start2 class and dont have to import all the classes of the package
  Start2 sts2=new Start2(); //creating an instance of Start2 so I can access the calcDisp() method. It highlights sts2 to green, which should not be.
  sts2.calcDisp(); // this is where the problem seems to be. NB gives the error that it does not exist
  // this method is created to collect the values and work with them.
  public void userInput(String name){
    jTextArea1.setText(name);
  }
}
```

I have left out the IDE generated code as they seem to be working fine.

Comment: You can not place statements outside a class. Your class declaration is missing completely. Add the class and put your initialisation statements into an initializer block or into the constructor.You might want to review https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html

Comment: @AndreasFester thank you for pointing that out. Since my code is really long I felt I should only bring out the relevant parts so that my problem can be solved quickly and accurately. Of course a class is declared in my code. Also I don't have comments outside of the classes. I will edit what I posted to avoid misunderstandiing. Also your suggestion is one of the things I tried and it did not work.

Comment: You should then not omit stuff that don't compile, but provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The missing part here, is C, for complete.

Comment: It would help enormously if you could post the complete class code

Comment: You have code outside of any function in class `PayRoll`. Also, when `Payroll' calls `calcDisp()` another Payroll object gets created. I think you need to rethink how these two frames interact.

Comment: @jr593 I have edited the post to include class declarations for both classes.

Comment: Yes, a more complete class would help. In the snippet above, you're trying to execute code (sts2.calcDisp()) outside of a method so it's not suprising that you don't get content assist.

Comment: @jr593 I am currently testing your suggestion, to see if it works. I don't want to jump into conclusions, as soon as I read your comment I rushed to NB to change where I put the code in PayRoll. So now the code is inside the userInput method of the PayRoll class and I get a list of methods available to the instance of 'Start2' (ie sts2) including calcDisp(). I will post back to provide the outcome. Thank you. Why did this happen? Can't I make an instance outside of a function/method? I am determined to learn the ins and outs of JavaSE.

Comment: Ok my problem was that the code was outside of a method block, I have now placed it inside the userInput method of PayRoll. But now I have rectified that, the values are not displayed inside of the JTextArea as I am retrieving them from the user with a JTextField and placing them in a variable. It is this variable that I'm using on the TextArea. What would anyone suggest as the best way to get the values (some strings some floats) from the Start2 class to the PayRoll class?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the fact that you call `calcDisp()` outside of any block.

There are several ways to have your code working:

1. Using a constructor (recommended).

   ```
   package Solution_screens;
   import home.Start2;

   public class PayRoll extends javax.swing.JFrame {
     Start2 sts2;
     public PayRoll() {
       sts2 = new Start2();
       sts2.calcDisp();
     }
     public void userInput(String name){
       jTextArea1.setText(name);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Using the initialization block

   ```
   package Solution_screens;
   import home.Start2;

   public class PayRoll extends javax.swing.JFrame {
     Start2 sts2;
     {
       sts2 = new Start2();
       sts2.calcDisp();
     }
     public void userInput(String name){
       jTextArea1.setText(name);
     }
   }
   ```

This should fix your current issue. I have more reserve about the rest of the code and hope that what you omitted is correct, because as it is, you code won't ever do anything.

Comment: this could work to, but I have realised my mistake. The thing is now the values received from the user in Start2 class are not being set in JtextArea of PayRoll class. I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do cross imports, like package A imports Package B
>   to access its methods then in reverse Package B imports Package A to
>   access its methods.

First of all this approach is not suggested. It may cause security problems. [(See details)](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=60752360)

Secondly, you create an instance of the class `PayRoll` inside the `Start2`class and create an instance of `Start2` class inside `PayRoll` class mutually. That's another wrong approach.

You must see _Design Pattern_s (especially *Observer Pattern*) to have a solution about your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the attention given to this topic. To start with the initial problem was that my code was outside of a block so I could not access any of the methods and NetBeans was unable to provide me with suggestions asides the new it kept on displaying.

So to send the values over this is it:

Start2 class

```
package home;
import Solution_screens.*;

public class Start2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
//this is the Start2 class it recieves user input via GUI then sends to PayRoll class in different package ie Solutions_screens)
public void calcDisp(){
//this method is called from here using button below. it collects and sends the values over
String firstname = jTextField1.getText();
String sal1 = jTextField5.getText();
float sal = Integer.parseInt(sal1);
PayRoll p = new PayRoll(); //creating instance of the PayROll class so I can send retrieved values over there
p.userInput(firstname, sal); //userInput method is defined in PayRoll class
p.setVisible(true);//use same instance to show the PayRoll GUI
}
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                         
// this button was dragged in using NB DnD
//no need creating another instance of PayRoll class just call the calcDisp method created above and it sends users retreived data over.

calcDisp();

}
}
```

Now the PayRoll class

```
package Solution_screens;
import home.Start2;

public class PayRoll extends javax.swing.JFrame {
//here I only need the Start2 class and dont have to import all the classes of the package


// this method is created to collect the values and work with them.
public void userInput(String name, String ssal){
jTextArea1.setText("Payroll Calculation for: " +name +"\t" "Salary is : "+ssal);
}
}
```

There is no need to call calcDisp() in PayRoll Class, the button from Start2 deals with it. I can even declare and set other variables and send them to PayRoll. There problem solved.